# Transmitting as iBeacon in XAMARIN - AltBeacon library

Tags: android-studio, xamarin.android, ibeacon, altbeacon

I have come across a problem with iBeacon transmission in AltBeacon library in XAMARIN.
In Android Studio, this code works perfect (I can detect created iBeacon on iPhone). I am using Android 5:

```
mBeaconTransmitter = new BeaconTransmitter(this, new BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24"));
Beacon beacon = new Beacon.Builder()
                .setId1("FDA50693-A4E2-4FB1-AFCF-C6EB07647825")
                .setId2("1000")
                .setId3("2000")
                .setManufacturer(0x004C)
                .setTxPower(-59)
                .setDataFields(Arrays.asList(new Long[] {0l}))
                .build();
mBeaconTransmitter.startAdvertising(beacon);
```

However, I have not managed to attain the same result in XAMARIN (Visual Studio). I cannot detect created iBeacon on iPhone in this case:

```
        var iBeaconParser = new BeaconParser();
        iBeaconParser.SetBeaconLayout("m:2-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24");
        BeaconTransmitter beaconTransmitter = new BeaconTransmitter(ApplicationContext, iBeaconParser);
        var beacon1 = new AltBeacon.Builder().SetId1("FDA50693-A4E2-4FB1-AFCF-C6EB07647825")
            .SetId2("1000").SetId3("2000").SetTxPower(-59).SetManufacturer(0x004C).Build();
        beaconTransmitter.StartAdvertising(beacon1);
```

The transmission also works in the second case. Other Android device could detect the created iBeacon. It was unsuccessful to detect the iBeacon on iPhone.

Thank you for any advice.

Comment: Usually when detections fail on iOS but work on Android that means the manufacturer code is not getting set.  Is it somehow possible this part of the Xamarin code is not working? `SetManufacturer(0x004C)`

Comment: You are right. I put a break point and manufacturer field is 0. I am surprised.

Comment: I am not able to set a property manufacturer in XAMARIN. I cannot change its value directly.

Answer (score 0):

Hey buddy it's been almost 3 years you have ask this question so I don't know that is it still relevant for you or not but my be this will help others.

I have seen this code this is absolutely right for the beacon broadcasting and I will suggest to check that if you have bind `IBeaconconsumer` with beacon manage in the initialization function  `Bind((IBeaconConsumer)Plugin.CurrentActivity.CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity);` or check that if you have use _tagRegion and this refers to right one.

Hope this will help.